# Near Real Time Event Processing From Web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, api, rest, service

I'm after a couple of ideas or opinions if you do not mind.  I'm a trying to understand the best approach for a solution which needs to process near real time events received over a Web API using REST and JSON.  There could be several events that are received every second.

As an event is received its processed against a number of rules which could be computationally expense to perform.  Each event would be processed against `100s` of rules to find a match.  A rule might be based on multiple events, and as such I need to store state in memory, not disk or database as performance will become key.  The Rules will be pushed in from a Database as a one time exercise and again will be held in memory.  If a rule is changed, it will be re-pushed.

Would it be best to write this is a single C# WebAPI Application that receives and correlates the Events.  Or a WebAPI, and windows service?

If the later how do I get the API and Windows Service to pass data between each other?These could be on the same or separate servers

With the Windows Service rather than start a new thread for every event respecified, im thinking I should create an event queue or buffer (some sort of FIFO Array).  Id have several buffers assigned to different threads or processes to achieve some level of parallelism.

Similarly if I produced this as just a WebAPI, is it possible to create the Queuing/threading approach?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be too big to provide single answer for. Designing system like this depends on multitude of factors such as requirements of the system.

For general event processing solution it's good idea to have web api which saves the events into queue system that has stores the events for later processing. Queue can be external service such as Azure Storage Queue or custom any custom queue implementation that you're able to communicate with and that satisfies your requirements.

Then you would have single or multiple event processors that retrieve events for processing from queue. The event processor could be custom program written by you. Generally the queue should have a way to lease an event so that in case processor fails (crashes) the event is returned to the queue for another processor to process. Once processor has processed the event it can be permanently removed from the queue.

Having that type of architecture is good starting point for building reliable and possibly even scalable solution for processing events. Of course one has to consider the performance of the queue as it could become bottleneck if the amount of events per second is huge.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  The events are being archived to a NoSQL DB via another WebAPI that I have.  It is possible to batch read these events every period say 60seconds, however i feel this would put much more load on the system, than processing the events as they arrive.

Comment: There is a work around that I can use for this, which is by creating a tailable cursor in the NoSQL.  Which means I can read them directly from the DB as they are written by the API.  However these kind of cursors dont support delete events.

i am doing something similar in another appliance, where by when I have worked on the event, I update the event leaving only the ID as a valid field in the DB.

id prefer to avoid this as it doubles the workload on the DB.  However its  solution.....